# Executable launches via Python but does not save .csv

Tags: python, csv, exe, executable, launch

I am working on a Python script that launches an executable.
I can launch the executable, but it does not do what is expected. Let say the exe is called `myprogram.exe` and in in the `C:\` directory, then this is my code:

```
import subprocess  
subprocess.call([r"C:\myprogram.exe"])
```

This executable should save some data to a .csv file. If I launch the exe by double clicking it, it does what it should do. But when I launch it via Python it does not save the data to a csv file. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: This could be a permissions problem -- perhaps you are not running Python with write privileges, but double clicking the exe automatically launches it with those privileges.

Comment: Does executable requires admin privileges when run via double clicking?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction, it does not ask for admin privileges. If I double click the exe file it immediately start running. How can I find out if it needs write priviliges?

Comment: Stupid question: can it be that the path used by this program.exe is not the one you expect? Where does the program write to, when you run it with double click? Because it might be that it actually writes, but you don't find the file (?). What happens if you put the python script in C:\ and run Python from C:\ ?

Comment: It writes to the same folder the exe file is in, but now it does not write a csv at all.

Comment: Hmm, what happens when you run the program directly from a cmd window?

Comment: If I launch it from the cmd window it also does not save to a .csv file